# Why am i getting false while testing reg exp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is the following script returning false ?

```
var a = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s]+$/");
var b = "software engineer";
var c = "software.engineer";

var bool = a.test(b);
document.write(bool);
```

This is what i understand of the reg exp : *string could start with alphabet that could occur one or more than one time and end with space or alphabet that could occur one or more than one time.*

In that case it should return true !

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
var a = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\\s]+$");
```

OR:

```
var a = /^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
```

So no delimiters if you are using `new RegExp` and `new RegExp` also needs double escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining your regex as a string, which means the `/` delimiters are not necessary and actually being treated as part of the pattern.

The syntax is either:

```
var regex = /foo/;
or
var regex = new RegExp("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing your regex as a string, so JS syntax interferes with regex syntax. Use a literal instead:

```
var a = /^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
```

this is equivalent to:

```
var a = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\\s]+$");
```

except you don't need to escape your backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing string literals and regex literals. Either use:

```js
var a = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\\s]+$");
```

Or

```js
var a = /^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
```

More details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.